# Tableview reuse and imageView show wrong image in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a chat app, but I face a problem that about cell reuse.
My cell has imageView, and other label.
When I have new message, and I enter the chat view.
My imageView looks something wrong.
The imageView will show me two the same image.
What's wrong about my situation?
Thanks.

[Question video link in Youtube](https://youtu.be/doH1jKNnLGE)

```
class ChatroomViewController: UIViewController {

    var contents:[Message] = [Message]()
    var tableView:UITableView = UITableView()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
       super.viewDidLoad()

       let msgArray:[Message] = Message.getBy(now)
       contents = msgArray.reversed()

       if contents.count > 0 {
       self.tableView.scrollToRow(at: IndexPath.init(row: (self.contents.count)-1,section: 0), at: .top, animated: true)
       }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        guard contents.count != 0 else {
           let cell = UITableViewCell()
           return cell
        }
        let content = contents[indexPath.row] as Message

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "ImageCell", for: indexPath) as! ImageTableViewCell

        print("==) Index.row: \(indexPath.row)")

        cell.loadImageMessage(message: content, chatroomId: chatroomId)

        return youVillageImageCell

     }
}

class ImageTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

weak var user:User?
@IBOutlet weak var ImageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var NameLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var ChatImageView: MenuImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var DateLabel: UILabel!
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    ChatImageView.image = nil //Search from stackoverflow, but not working!! 
    ChatImageView.layer.masksToBounds = true 
    ChatImageView.layer.cornerRadius = defaultRadius

}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

override func prepareForReuse() {
    super.prepareForReuse()

    user = nil
    NameLabel.text = nil
    ImageView.image = nil
    ChatImageView.image = nil //Search from stackoverflow, but not working!! 
    DateLabel.text = nil
}

deinit{
    ImageView.removeFromSuperview()
    ChatImageView.removeFromSuperview()

    ImageView = nil
    ChatImageView = nil
    user = nil

    print("==) deinit ImageTableViewCell")
}

func loadImageMessage(message:Message, chatroomId:String) {

    messageImageFromUrl(imageView: youChatImageView, message: message, chatroomId: chatroomId, size: "m")
}
}
```

```
func messageImageFromUrl(imageView:UIImageView, message:Message, chatroomId:String, size:String) {

var documentsDirectoryURL:URL

documentsDirectoryURL = try! FileManager().url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: true).appendingPathComponent("\(chatroomId)/Image/")

let exist = FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: documentsDirectoryURL.path)

if !exist {

    do {
        try FileManager.default.createDirectory(atPath: documentsDirectoryURL.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
    } catch let error as NSError {
        debug(object: error)
    }
}

var imageUrl:String = message.content

let fileName = imageUrl.md5()
let fileURL = documentsDirectoryURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
if let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: fileURL.path) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        imageView.image = image
    }
    return
}

let urlString = URL(string: imageUrl)
DispatchQueue.global().async {
    let data = try? Data(contentsOf: urlString!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch
    if data != nil
    {
        if let image = UIImage(data: data!)
        {
            if !FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: fileURL.path) {

                var c = [UInt32](repeating: 0, count: 1)
                (data! as NSData).getBytes(&c, length: 1)
                switch (c[0]) {
                case 0xFF:

                    if let jpegData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.5) {

                        do {
                            try jpegData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
                        } catch {
                            debug(object: error)
                        }
                    }
                case 0x89:

                    if let pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image) {
                        do {
                            try pngData.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)
                        } catch {
                            debug(object: error)
                        }
                    }
                case 0x47:
                default:

                }

            } else {
                //print("file already exists")
            }

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                imageView.image = image
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Question Update**

sorry, I print indexPath.row in "cellForRowAt" and It also prints new message indexpathRow again like following message.

```
==) Index.row: 4
==) Index.row: 2
==) Index.row: 3
==) Index.row: 4
```

Comment: Add a `Message` property to your cell. When you do `imageView.image = image`, check that the `message` is the one corresponding the the image one (keeping track if the URL in the closure?).

Comment: It doesn’t look like a cell reuse problem to me. It looks more like a problem with the data being loaded and displayed either in the wrong order or before it has been fully loaded.

Comment: I think that SDWebImage (that does a good job), use `objc_setAssociatedObject(self, &imageURLKey, url, OBJC_ASSOCIATION_RETAIN_NONATOMIC);`. Then, it checks (with the reverse `objec_setAssociatedObject()`) then if it's the same the set the image.

Comment: Sorry ,I update my question. I just  use "scrollToRow" to the last row. Why call the twice about new message cell. Is this reason caused this situation?

Comment: I use "scrollToRow at Top" (not at bottom) .